# What is this part on the receptacle of the stove called and what is it for?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, stove

We have an older Whirlpool electric stove.  (Model # RS6750XVN)  One of the burners isn't working and when I lifted the top off I found a different type of receptacle.  Three of the receptacles look like this:

[image]

The 4th broken receptacle looks like this:

[image]

What is the name and/or function of the part that the arrow is pointing to?  It looks like the yellow wires used to attach to it...will there be a problem is I buy a normal receptacle replacement kit, run the two wires to it, and skip that end part?  Thanks for the help!

Here are some more photos with the part detached:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the wire broken off on both sides? Can you remove that piece and take a better picture of it?

Comment: Yes the 2 wires appear to have broken off of this piece.  Please see new pictures in post.

Answer (score 2):

The broken part is a thermal fuse. Here is a [link to the part](http://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/b5p13/Whirlpool-Range-Stove-Oven-Thermal-Fuse/3147833/492114?modelNumber=RS6750XVN1&ss=a13b5d586595&mr=1)

You should be able to pull the broken parts out of the end of the wires. They are just simple spade terminals.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to say,  but it looks like it is bolted to the metal frame, so I think it may be the ground for the frame. Okay now that you have more pictures Longneck is correct. It was hard to tell from the first angle.

Comment: I know there is a ground wire attached to the frame at another location, so I don't think this is the ground.  Unlike the other receptacles which have both wires running into them, this receptacle only has one wire running into it from the power source.  The other wire which I thought would have gone to the receptacle, goes to this piece on the frame.  And then a wire runs from this frame piece to the receptacle as if completing the circuit that way.